# PostgreSQL-filter where category is most common value

Tags: postgresql, mode

I'm attempting to use the mode() or most_common_vals() functions as a subquery criteria.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(request_id) AS total
FROM requests
WHERE category = (SELECT mode(category) AS modal_category FROM requests)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

However, I continue to receive an error regarding the non-existence of both functions.

Comment: What do you want to do if the data is multi-modal, i.e. there are two or more values which are "most common" values?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
with requests  (user_id,  request_id, category) as (
select 1, 111, 'A' union all
select 1, 111, 'A' union all
select 2, 111, 'A' union all
select 2, 111, 'B' union all
select 1, 111, 'B' union all
select 3, 111, 'B' union all
select 1, 111, 'B' union all
select 1, 111, 'C'  
 )

-- Below is actual query: 

select user_id, COUNT(request_id)  AS total
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(order by cnt desc) as rnk from (
        select requests.*, count(*) over(partition by category) as cnt from requests
    ) t
) tt 
where rnk = 1
group by user_id
order by total desc
limit 5
```

Here `user_id` and `COUNT(request_id)` are calculated only for  `'B'` category, because it is most common in this example.

Also please note that in case, if there is multiple most common categories, this query produces result from all of those categories.